# calling an external command as a subprocess in Scala

Tags: scala, subprocess

In Python, if I want to call an external command as a subprocess, I do the following:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd = ['cat', '-be']
out, err = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate("some input")
```

What's the standard way to do the same in Scala?  Using Java's ProcessBuilder I came up with the following, but it's pretty ugly:

```
def communicate(cmd: List[String], input: Option[String] = None): (String, String) = {

    val command = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
    cmd.foreach(command.add(_))

    val builder = new ProcessBuilder(command)
    val process = builder.start()

    val stdinWriter = new java.io.PrintWriter((new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(process.getOutputStream()))), true);
    val stdoutReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))
    val stderrReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()))

    input.foreach(stdinWriter.write(_))
    stdinWriter.close()

    def read(reader: java.io.BufferedReader): String = {
        val out = new ListBuffer[String]
        var line: String = reader.readLine()
        while (line != null) {
            out += line
            line = reader.readLine()
        }
        return out.result.mkString("\n")
    }

    val stdout = read(stdoutReader)
    val stderr = read(stderrReader)

    stdoutReader.close()
    stderrReader.close()

    return (stdout, stderr)

}

val (catout, caterr) = communicate(List("cat", "-be"), Some("some input"))
val (pwdout, pwderr) = communicate(List("pwd"))
```

Is there a better alternative built into Scala already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer here [How does the “scala.sys.process” from Scala 2.9 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013415/how-does-the-scala-sys-process-from-scala-2-9-work) shows how to use the new Scala 2.9 scala.sys.process.Process. If you don't use 2.9 you can use the process part of sbt; which the Scala process originates from.

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [OS-Lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) library, your code can be written as the following Scala:

```
@ val res = os.proc("cat", "-be").call(stdin = "some input")
res: os.CommandResult = CommandResult(0, List(Left(     1   some input)))

@ res.out.string
res3: String = "     1\tsome input"

@ res.err.string
res4: String = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Hav you looked at Apache commons exec http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html?

I've used it successfully from Scala a few years ago. Digged up some code:

```
def quickRun(command: String, allowedExitCodes: Array[Int]): String = {
  val executor = new DefaultExecutor()
  val outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val errorStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

  val pumpStreamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream, errorStream)
  executor.setStreamHandler(pumpStreamHandler)
  executor.setExitValues(allowedExitCodes)

  lazy val errorMsg = "Couldn't execute command: \"" + command + "\", errorStream: " + errorStream.toString()
  try {
    val exitValue = executor.execute(CommandLine.parse(command))
    if (executor.isFailure(exitValue)) {
      log.error(errorMsg)
      throw new CommandLineException(errorMsg)
    } else {
      return outputStream.toString()
    }
  } catch {
    case e: ExecuteException =>
      log.error(errorMsg)
      throw new CommandLineException(errorMsg)
    case e: IOException => throw new CommandLineException(errorMsg)
  }
}
```

But scala.sys.process looks better, I think you should use that if possible…