# How can I debug why a sys.process command from scala is failing with bad exit code (3) when it works from the command line?

Tags: scala, cassandra

I'm writing a simple function to test whether Cassandra is running on the local machine (by capturing the output of `service cassandra status`. The problem is that this command always exits with a bad return status of 3. I have successfully called `service cassandra stop` immediately prior to this command, and have even tried running `status` in a loop to see if there was some race condition (it seems to reliably fail with status 3 for a long time). However, running `service cassandra status` through the shell works. Any ideas what the issue may be, or even just how to debug this?

```
  private def isCassandraStopped(): Boolean = {
    val s = Seq("sudo", "sh", "-c", "service cassandra status").!!
    val r = " * Cassandra is not running" == s
    if (!r) logger.info(s"Cassandra is not stopped: #$s#")
    r
  }
```

This is the line that succeeds prior to executing the above method:

```
  Seq("sudo", "sh", "-c", "service cassandra stop").!
```

Comment: Can you post the init.d script? is it hand made or came with a package on your system? Additionally run this from shell: `service cassandra status > /tmp/my.log` and `echo $?` right after and see if any output goes to screen at all and what was an exit status.

Comment: There's a lot in the file, but to the best of my knowledge, we didn't change anything in it from the standard cassandra package. I ran `echo $?` and it looks like it normally returns with status 3 when cassandra is not running, so I can just check the return status code and not do any string comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading process output with `!!` any non-zero exit status throws an exception by default as described in the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder). You can try to work around it and read the output as well as get the process exit status in ways described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411728/scala-process-capture-standard-out-and-exit-code).

By default exit status 3 should mean that the program is not running as described [here](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html). However, this might not be respected by your init script. So the best thing is to read the script and make sure that it returns the exit code 3 in that case.

So your options are:

- read the exit code only if it's reliable
- check how your run script is implemented and duplicate the process status check logic yourself - usually it checks that pid file exists and the process with that pid is running (checkpid).
- read both output and exit status as described in other SO QAs
- read all lines without throwing an exception with `lines_!`: `Process("your command here").lines_!`. You will not have an exit status in this case.

Usually exit status is more reliable in properly written shell scripts than output parsing.