# Passing process stdout to outside function

Tags: scala, processbuilder

I'm trying to implement a function that starts a process and returns its stdout as `InputStream`.

```
def getStuff(): InputStream = ???
```

Seems pretty easy to do in Java but I can't figure out how to do it using `sys.process` in Scala.

Comment: Maybe this question/answers can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411728/scala-process-capture-standard-out-and-exit-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the output of a command to `OutputSteam` with `#>`. Then you just need to copy `OutputStream` to `InputStream`:

```
import scala.sys.process._
import java.io._
import scala.io.Source

def getStuff(): InputStream = {
  val os   =  new ByteArrayOutputStream
  ("echo 'Hello'" #> os).!
  new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
}

Source.fromInputStream(getStuff()).mkString //"Hello"
```