# Call Python script from Scala?

Tags: python, scala

I want to call my python script `runner.py` from Scala program, I doing it like this:

runner.py:

`print("testing")`

`program.scala:

`val res = "python3 runner.py" !`

The problem is that this only return `0`, but not the printed output. How can I get that in Scala?

Comment: To run external programs, you can use methods from the package scala.sys.process  https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/index.html

Comment: Does this contain enough material to either answer your question, or at least formulate more precisely what the problem is?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411728/scala-process-capture-standard-out-and-exit-code In particular, [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15438493/2707792) shows how to capture everything.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [ScalaDocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html), `!` returns the process exit code. `!!` returns the process StdOut. If you need both you'll want to add a `ProcessLogger`.