# How to start "python.exe" as subprocess in scala?

Tags: python, scala

My requirement is to form an integration between scala and python. How do I start "python.exe" and executes python commands from scala.

I have tried the code snippet from following link, but it doesn't seems to be working. Could you please help me this ?

[How does the “scala.sys.process” from Scala 2.9 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013415/how-does-the-scala-sys-process-from-scala-2-9-work)

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Do you *have* to use CPython? Why not just use Jython and be done with it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jorg.... Since I faced some issues with 'jep' library, I moved to this process. Is there any other option available ?

Comment: @yoganathank : "it doesn't seem to be working" **how**? Please provide the exact code you're using as well as the erroneous output.

Answer (score 1):

The process API is quite contrived and absolutely horribly (= not) documented. I often go back to the Java API because it makes more sense to me.

Here is an example. Overwriting the `os` variable to "store" the output-stream seems like an idiotic approach (in Java you can just query the output-stream from the process). Perhaps the designers of the API can enlighten us what they were thinking. Probably there is a more elegant solution:

```scala
import sys.process._

var os: java.io.OutputStream = _
val python = Process(Seq("python","-i")).run(BasicIO.standard(os = _) /* WTF? */)

def pushLine(s: String): Unit = {
  os.write(s"$s\n".getBytes("UTF-8"))
  os.flush()
}

pushLine("1+1")
pushLine("exit()")
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to undertake a very similar project. Rather than just executing a python script and parsing the output, i needed to start up some python code and send commands to it to execute and respond back. After some time trying to do this communication over STDIN/STDOUT, I opted for using ZeroMQ as my interop communications channel

By doing this, the execution of code became as simple as

```
val process = s"python commandRunner.py $port".run()
```

where `$port` is the port on which my code is listening for the python code to connect back to me via ZeroMQ, while the `commandRunner` script runs a simple ZeroMQ event-loop

Comment: Yes, ZeroMQ is a very powerfull ( ... and fast to get used to ) framework for trully distributed computing [+1 Arne.