# How to run shell command programmatically in scala

Tags: scala, shell

I have some shell commands that would get dynamically generated in my scala script, how can I run them inside the scala script?

Code snippet below:

```
var filename = xxxxxx

filename = "This File"

import sys.process._
"hdfs dfs -rm " + filename
```

Literally I want to run shell command:
hdfs dfs -rm "This File"

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method called `!` to run a command, using string interpolation of the filename variable, you can run it like this:

```
s"hdfs dfs -rm $filename".!
```

See more in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013972/6176274